# Jmeter transaction controller recording(s) not appearing under transactions on Mac

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter on Mac and it's not showing transaction controller recordings as it shows on Windows. Can someone please let me know what's the problem and where the recordings are saved(if it's saving them). I've attached pictures and all the steps that I'm taking.

I'm following all the steps that he states on the following video which starts at 36m31s. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKptzknsetA&ab_channel=PSTA%3APerformance%26SecurityTestingAcademy

I have also attached a pictures describing the problem and as stated before, following the instructions using the above Youtube video. The pictures are at the following link - https://imgur.com/a/mnLEL0Z

Thank you!

I tried troubleshooting and looking for help but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, the recorded [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers go to the [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) normally:

[image]

If the samplers are being recorded elsewhere you will be able to re-arrange the request using Cut and Paste.

If the samplers are not recording check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, it might be the case JMeter and/or browser is not properly configured, i.e. proxy settings are not correct or certificate is not imported into the browser. See documentation on [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for more details.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you don't need to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: I tried the same thing and it's not working for me. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I have made a screen recording and here's the link - https://youtu.be/JrfvkxuqinA

Thank you!

Comment: You've set proxy for [`HTTP`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol only and you're opening the website you're trying to record using [`HTTPS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) protocol. In case of HTTPS my piece of advice for certificate installation is a must. Have you considered using JMeter Chrome Extension? It's not just easier, it also provides [automatic correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/auto-correlation-template) of dynamic parameters.

Comment: Perfect! It's working now after using HTTPS proxy server. Thank you for that. Can you let me know how to install the certificate? Also, can you let me know or point out a resource to learn Jmeter Chrome extension? I downloaded it but it looks overwhelming with so many options. 

Thanks again